# Typescript how to enforce record key to be string when extended

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function that will accept an object as a map and that a further nested function will utilize it's keys(I'll need the value as well in the future):

```
  function exec(a: string) {
    return a;
  }
  
  function one<T extends Record<string, any>>(a: T) {
    return <K extends keyof T>(b: K) => {
    exec(b);// TS2345: Argument of type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
   };  
 }
```

but I get this error `TS2345: Argument of type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.` since object keys could be number | Symbol as well and not strictly string.
Can it be done without `exec(b.toString())`?

Comment: `K extends string & keyof T`? If that meets your needs I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks yes! isn't there less verbose solution?

Comment: So "less verbose" means "adds fewer than nine characters"? I don't know; why do you care about *verbosity* here? Is that a requirement you want to add to the question? If not it seems out of scope.  How would you like to proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz no it's ok thanks! if you write an answer i'll upvote it

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) does not prevent there from being non-`string` keys (it only means that any `string` keys that exist need to have properties compatible with the index signature, which for `Record<string, any>` is exceedingly lax).  And the same thing holds for [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters with [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) like `T extends U`; even if `U` doesn't have a particular property key, it doesn't mean `T` can't have that key.  Essentially, object types in TypeScript are *open* and not *exact* (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)), and in most circumstances the compiler will not prohibit excess properties.

This means you can call `one` like this:

```
const sym = Symbol();
const a = { str: 1, [sym]: 2 }
const fn = one(a); // okay
fn("str"); // okay
fn(sym); // okay
```

which is why the implementation of `one` complains that `b` might not be a `string`.

---

If you want to prevent that, you'll need to constrain `K` to be not just `keyof T`, but just the subtype of `keyof T` also assignable to `string`.  The easiest way to express that is to just [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `string` with `keyof T`:

```
function one<T extends Record<string, any>>(a: T) {
    return <K extends string & keyof T>(b: K) => {
        exec(b); // okay
    };
}
```

Now the compiler knows that `b` must be `keyof T` as well as a `string`.  And now you get the desired error if you try to call the function returned from `one` with a non-`string` input:

```
const sym = Symbol();
const a = { str: 1, [sym]: 2 }
const fn = one(a); // okay
fn("str"); // okay
fn(sym); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOYdAGyQG8AoJMpAMwFdh4AXDAe2CQgA8J4AKEALiSh1MwLAEoipclLQQ6VNCxABuSWQC+xVZRr0mLZhAA8AFVZs6EYABMoSAEqdGaK4cHCsAGiQhgATwB8-jz8xuIkUtKy8iyGANJmFta2ANYQvowUSMZBAEb8seIAvP4SEWVmnFw5okpIAPR1rGhoTgCEWlJqKp2aUvDMggK+YEiFSADKwzmMeFw1Wv3AgyCjRAJC-ACMXgDaUMMAuvwATEgafQN0lCxjBjw19Y2MySC+WhTAXABEbl8PDUhnq93p99mB-k8Xm9NBpQJBYAhkAAxDBsUrkai0BjMCrcPjrdxhDrkGRyBTebrkDTvHTY-TAIymdiJGz2RzOVxCXCebx+QLBLJE8pIUnRJBxBKWVlublIABkSFS6Uy2Sq+SKJXCwvI7Eq1VqAKBb2FXS01IuSyuYNWkzA01m8wty1WhAJW12YKOSFO53Ii0GH1WdxAEMBUJB31+oaNEbBoYgzScxDUQA)